# Purpose of osgi and sling frameworks in AEM. Why do we need 2 frameworks

Tags: aem

I just try to understand what is the main purpose of the sling and osgi frameworks
I have seen in many documents like osgi framework is for bundles and sling is java based web framework. can anyone please explain in detail. and why do we need 2 frameworks for AEM

Comment: The question you asked is just so bad. These frameworks serve a completely different purpose obviously. it's as if you asked why do we need trains, cars, planes, ships isn't one transportation method enough?

Comment: The answer from @ub1k covered the most important parts. But in it's essence OSGi is just a standard. One implementation of that standard is Apache Felix which is used by AEM. Apache Felix and Sling are used to solve different problems in AEM. You can not substitute one for the other. You need both.

Answer (score 3):

I'll keep it simple:

OSGi is a component container - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi
lets you create your application out of 'fragments' that are called OSGi bundles.

Sling framework - https://sling.apache.org/ - gives you CRUD access to JCR repository via a restful API. It lives within OSGi as one of its bundles. Sling is used extensively within AEM authoring - all the authoring actions (dialogs) are made through REST calls to JCR via sling.

please look at the following image - it describes the architecture quite well:
https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/exploring/architecture-overview/_jcr_content/par/image.img.png/1382016883799.png

Comment: Thanks for the info ub1k